# How should I enable hardware graphics acceleration in Chromium web-browser running on Ubuntu MATE 21.10 on RPi 4 (armhf)?

Tags: chromium, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, opengl, 21.10

I have just installed Ubuntu MATE 21.10 (32-bit, armhf) on my Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 Gb of RAM. Note: I need 32-bit version to have [Modelica compiler available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=groovy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=modelicac). All settings are default. Information about video driver is below:

```
$ lsmod | grep drm
drm_kms_helper        282624  3 vc4
cec                    65536  2 vc4,drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   540672  12 v3d,vc4,gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper

$ grep -E "^dtoverlay|^max_framebuffers|^gpu_mem|^hdmi" /boot/firmware/config.txt 
max_framebuffers=2
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
gpu_mem=128

$ cat /proc/device-tree/soc/firmwarekms@7e600000/status
okay

$ cat /proc/device-tree/v3dbus/v3d@7ec04000/status
okay

$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Broadcom
OpenGL renderer string: V3D 4.2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 21.2.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 21.2.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Then I installed Chromium browser as simple as `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`, launched it for first time to enable the following options on *`chrome://flags`*:

- **Override software rendering list** aka `#ignore-gpu-blocklist`;
- **GPU rasterization** aka `#enable-gpu-rasterization`;
- **Zero-copy rasterizer** aka `#enable-zero-copy`;
- **Enables Display Compositor to use a new gpu thread.** aka `#enable-drdc`;
- **Out-of-process 2D canvas rasterization.** aka `#canvas-oop-rasterization`.

then relaunched it using `chromium --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder` command.

Desite all these steps done, on *`chrome://gpu`* Chromium says that GPU acceleration is not enabled:

> **Graphics Feature Status**
>
> - Canvas: *Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled*
> - Canvas out-of-process rasterization: *Disabled*
> - Compositing: *Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled*
> - Multiple Raster Threads: *Disabled*
> - Out-of-process Rasterization: *Disabled*
> - OpenGL: *Disabled*
> - Rasterization: *Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled*
> - Raw Draw: *Disabled*
> - Skia Renderer: Enabled
> - Video Decode: *Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled*
> - Vulkan: *Disabled*
> - WebGL: *Disabled*
> - WebGL2: *Disabled*

So the question is in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is that Chromium is shipped as Snap, so VA-API is not available as we are running on ARM.

So the first step is obvious - remove Snap version of Chromium by `sudo snap remove chromium`.

The second step is installation of Chromium as deb-package from RaspberryPi OS repository using below commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 82B129927FA3303E
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main"

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-chromium
Package: *
Pin: release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: chromium*
Pin: release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation
Pin-Priority: 1000
EOF

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Then launch Chromium to configure it as usual - enable the following options on *`chrome://flags`*:

- **Override software rendering list** aka `#ignore-gpu-blocklist`;
- **GPU rasterization** aka `#enable-gpu-rasterization`;
- **Zero-copy rasterizer** aka `#enable-zero-copy`;
- **Enables Display Compositor to use a new gpu thread.** aka `#enable-drdc`;
- **Out-of-process 2D canvas rasterization.** aka `#canvas-oop-rasterization`.

Relaunch it using `chromium-browser --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder`, visit *`chrome://gpu`* to ensure that you have all (excluding Vulkan) options enabled:

> **Graphics Feature Status**
>
> - Canvas: Hardware accelerated
> - Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Enabled
> - Compositing: Hardware accelerated
> - Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
> - Out-of-process Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
> - OpenGL: Enabled
> - Rasterization: Hardware accelerated on all pages
> - Skia Renderer: Enabled
> - Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
> - Vulkan: Disabled
> - WebGL: Hardware accelerated
> - WebGL2: Hardware accelerated

To  make `--enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder` flag permanent one should edit the relevant config-file programmatically as shown below:

```
echo 'CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder"' | sudo tee /etc/chromium.d/92-vaapi-hardware-decoding
```

As the result all web-players will play 1080p without lags and tearing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guide, question bro, how can i stay sure that i am using "--enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder", i am in windows using a other program that execute chromium, i've set this parameter but i am not sure if it was applied, what should i do for check it?