# Can hardware accelerated video decoding be enabled for Kodi on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: video, raspberrypi, 23.04, hardware-acceleration, kodi

I've been running 23.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB) for some time, but Kodi (20) from Debian does not seem to use hardware decoding, neither for h.264 nor h.265. I've tested with reasonable resolutions such as 720p and 1080p, including some h.264 Youtube viedos that HW decode fine on a Pi 3 (so no problem with the files).

What is missing for Kodi to utilize the hardware decoders on a Pi 4? Can it be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The raspi 4 has hevc (mp4) decoding by default ([described here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=268356)). I'm using kodi (libreELEC) on raspi4 without any additional tweaks or a bought license.
However, the Linux distros struggled to get all codes implemented for the new VC6 GPU, but a V4L2 M2M interface has been provided, which could be used by ffmpeg. Kodi should support the interface natively.

You can check your abilities by executing

```
$ cat /proc/device-tree/soc/firmwarekms@7e600000/status

$ cat /proc/device-tree/v3dbus/v3d@7ec04000/status
```

Both should answer "okay"

Do not use "snap" software - it won't support the underlying hardware. This is [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1386048/906933) in length

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So, the first answers `disabled` and the second path isn't valid (no `v3d...` directory). Should I have expected something else on a pretty vanilla system without any manual intervention by me? The system is 23.04 upgraded from a 22.10 install.